# Trying to use bcessa/php-stripe for my codeigniter but not sure how to do it properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

I'm not a pro in codeigniter yet and trying to work with payment system 'Stripe' for the first time.

Not sure how to do it properly

User [this](https://github.com/bcessa/php-stripe)

But some step by step guide would be nice as not to sure where to put which file and when I'm doing my own guesses it is giving me all sort of errors.

Can someone guide me how to integrate this with my Codeigniter. Please write a dumb guide coz after all day I'm feeling once :(

Thanks for your help

---

Edited

When I load provided library in Git in my file it gives me following two errors.

> Message: Missing argument 1 for Stripe::__construct(), called in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/goclean/system/core/Loader.php on line 1099
>   and defined
>
> Filename: libraries/Stripe.php
>
> Line Number: 31
>
> AND
>
> Message: Undefined variable: params
>
> Filename: libraries/Stripe.php
>
> Line Number: 33

Comment: Why don't you ask the guy who wrote this library?

Comment: @Alex good idea but seems like he didn't update it for 4 years and some issues already mentioned there but no replies by him.

Comment: He has an email (look at his github profile: https://github.com/bcessa). You can try connect directly. By the way it would be useful if you wrote what you've tried. There are code samples on the github page. So what the result of its integration?

Comment: @Alex post edited with errors when I load the library

Comment: Dude, look carefully at usage example. $stripe = new Stripe( $config );
Stripe constructor takes one argument. What do you do when create instance of Stripe?

Comment: @Alex bro just tell me what should I do :( I have created a stripe.php in config folder exactly how it appears in usage. What am I missing

Comment: I am not a specialist in Codeigniter, but I think you should specify (if you haven't yet) $config values in your config.php file. I mean the values related to stripe library. Try to put first code block from usage right into your config file and look what happens.